# FactoryGirl with params by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

There is the following code:

```
  factory :item do
    name        'Some name'
    description 'Some description'
    cost        100
    cooking_time 10
    menu
  end
```

This code sets up cooking_time as a constant value, but how can I pass param for this param with default value (10)? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create(:item, cooking_time: 20)
```

For more inforamation please go through [Factory Girl Documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md)

Answer (score 0):

You just override the attribute when you use the factory in your test:

```
create(:item, cooking_time: 20)
```